# Select Specific ID using Jquery

Tags: jquery, selector

I have a game board which is broken up into different section ex. game1, game2...
I am trying to use jquery to add a class to a specific div with an ID. So in my PHP below:

```
<div id="game1" class="playarea">
    <div id="K12" class="playnum" data-game="game1">12</div>
    <div id="D61" class="playnum" data-game="game1">61</div>
    <div id="N29" class="playnum" data-game="game1">29</div>
    <div id="P06" class="playnum" data-game="game1">06</div>
    <div id="X54" class="playnum" data-game="game1">54</div>
</div>

<div id="game2" class="playarea">
    <div id="K12" class="playnum" data-game="game1">12</div>
    <div id="D61" class="playnum" data-game="game1">61</div>
    <div id="N29" class="playnum" data-game="game1">29</div>
    <div id="P06" class="playnum" data-game="game1">06</div>
    <div id="X54" class="playnum" data-game="game1">54</div>
</div>
```

I want to .addClass to the div with ID "D61" ONLY from the DIV with ID "game1".  This function will be performed from a button so there is no context like "this". I have been trying .children() and even .find() or .attr() but no luck.

Right now I am using

```
 $('[id="D61"]').addClass("selected");
```

But the problem is that it will .addClass() to both DIVs in game1 and in game2. How can I better narrow this down?

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context. Firstly fix it using classes instead. Secondly, just use relevant method to target specific child, e.g once using class: `$(this).children('.D61').addClass("selected");`

Comment: You have to use D61 as class then use this $('#game1 .D61').addClass("selected");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like following.

```
$('#game1 #D61').addClass('selected').
```

You are duplicating `id`. `id` should be unique. You can use class `D61` instead of `id` like following.

```
<div class="D61 playnum" data-game="game1">61</div>
```

And then the `js` will be like this.

```
$('#game1 .D61').addClass('selected').
```

Comment: Thank you. Many have the correct answer of course. You are all right about the duplicate IDs, so I changed them all to an additional class element like above.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using the code below:

```
$('#game1 > #D61').addClass("selected");
```

The div with `id="game"` is the parent with its immediate children with `id="D61"`, so it will target only the div with id="game1".

Answer (score 0):

```
var $reqElement = $("#game1").find("#D61");
reqElement.addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll comment some design problem 1st :

1. Unlike custom attributes id is a standard attributes that is supposed to be unique accross the page (see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp).
2. to search for an id you can just search for #D61. see https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Now the answer : check this link : https://api.jquery.com/find/

So that'll give : 
    $('#game1').find('#KD61');

Comment: hum be carefull : some frameworks like angular strip automatically data- prefix, this is specially usefull on directive level in angular. I don't know about how other frameworks (and jQuery) handle that. Maybe more like data-game-id :)